# How to refresh the screen when back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I have scenario with two screens.

1. Screen 1 shows data from from API in list format
2. There is a "+" button in menu bar
3. Clicking this button takes user to screen 2
4. User can enter some info on screen 2 and press the "save" button on top of this screen. This does a POST to my API and saves the data.

After saving, I would like to put the user back to screen 1. I've done that with this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("save")) {
        new CreateSomethingTask(this,enteredName.getText().toString(), id).execute();
        Intent listscreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowListActivity.class);
        startActivity(listscreen);
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, the added item is not shown. If I close my app and open it again then the item shows up.

Is there a good way to handle this? I like how the Github Android app handles this when creating a new Gist. But I'm not sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start your screen2 with startActivityForResult(). That way you could send a result back and a code and proceed to refresh your screen1. See example : [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)

Answer (score -1):

Below function maybe help you, didn't tried.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    callFunctionToRefreshList();
    //or redraw data from api
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
}
```